# Borrar Control Con Click En WindowsForms C#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Necesito que al dar click a un botón, "seleccione" ese botón, y al dar click a un botón de borrar, ese control se elimine. ¿Cómo podría realizar eso?.

Comment: Has intentado algo? Podrías usar una variable para almacenar el ultimo botón pulsado y eliminarlo posteriormente

Comment: Ya lo había pensado, pero que tipo de variable podría ser?

Comment: Ehmm...una variable de tipo `Button` por ejemplo? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Button mLastSelection;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Button btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = "Seleccione" + i;
                btn.Location = new Point(0, btn.Height * i);
                btn.Click += new EventHandler((sender, args) =>
                {
                    mLastSelection = sender as Button;
                });
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
            }

            Button borrarSeleccion = new Button();
            borrarSeleccion.Location = new Point(borrarSeleccion.Width + 15, 0);
            borrarSeleccion.Text = "Borrar Seleccionado";
            borrarSeleccion.Click += new EventHandler((sender, args) =>
            {
                mLastSelection?.Dispose();
            });

            this.Controls.Add(borrarSeleccion);
        }
    }
```